# Using UIPage Control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have been trying to build a app where you touch three different buttons and then go to there new view. Its it possible to use a UIPage Control? If so How would you go about doing that. For example I have three views. Apple, Orange, Cherry. I would like the user to flick between these three views. I need them to be three separate views i can't just have the image change.

How would I go about using the UIPage Control and switching views?

Answer (score 0):

`UIPageControl` doesn't deal with switching views itself, it just provides the dots that are typically displayed at the bottom of a paged view and it can be tapped to go one page forward or backward (instead of swiping the actual view). The actual view that displays the content is typically a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`.

When the control is tapped, it sends the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event to its target. You'll then have to scroll the `UIScrollView` to the right page yourself.